# Actions on Google Assistant Sign-in Account Linking. Where should the Google Id be?

Tags: python, jwt, actions-on-google

I'm building an Action for Google Assistant and I'm trying to use account linking with the Sign-in option described here https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in .

It was all right and I get all the right conditions in the flow of my scenes to believe that the user is correctly Verified and his account is linked.

Now my problem is that **I can't find the Google Id named in the documentation anywhere.**
To be more specific, I'm at this point in the docs:

[image: Part of the doc about receiving a Google Id]

It explicitly says "After the user authorizes your action to access their Google profile, you will receive a Google ID token that contains the user's Google profile information in every subsequent request to your action." but I can't find it in the requests to my webhook.

Here is an example of the requests body I get:

```
{
  "handler": {
    "name": "testScene"
  },
  "intent": {
    "name": "",
    "params": {
      "AccountLinkingSlot": {
        "original": "",
        "resolved": "LINKED"
      }
    },
    "query": ""
  },
  "scene": {
    "name": "TestScene",
    "slotFillingStatus": "UNSPECIFIED",
    "slots": {},
    "next": {
      "name": "actions.scene.END_CONVERSATION"
    }
  },
  "session": {
    "id": "ABwppHEW23oRCX4FofxCg_rIDBo9UepL-Tw6u-AV3vKTzPoC6c9wkP0xjG7DoGqEZOWA2tlMYtcsbDcmQUw",
    "params": {
      "AccountLinkingSlot": "LINKED"
    },
    "typeOverrides": [],
    "languageCode": ""
  },
  "user": {
    "locale": "en-US",
    "params": {},
    "accountLinkingStatus": "LINKED",
    "verificationStatus": "VERIFIED",
    "packageEntitlements": [],
    "lastSeenTime": "2020-10-27T20:35:59Z"
  },
  "home": {
    "params": {}
  },
  "device": {
    "capabilities": [
      "SPEECH",
      "RICH_RESPONSE",
      "LONG_FORM_AUDIO"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've only found that if you use nodejs you can just put your own client id in your system and it will take care of it, but I am using fastApi (Python) and can't find anything in the doc about what to do other than what is written in the already linked docs.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer while randomly looking around. Hope this is going to be useful.

In the request headers I get from google there are two headers:

- "google-assistant-signature",
- "authorization".

Both had the typical three-parts-dot-separated format I was expecting to see in a Json Web Token.

Now I tried to decrypt them with both the keys I get from the url in the documentation https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs and apparently the first of the two is a valid key to do the job.

**The authorization token contains the user data I was looking for**.

There are still unanswered questions:

- **Why do I get two different tokens and then have to guess which one to use?** I've kept them both in my code with a system of trial and error just in case google sends me the tokens encrypted randomly with one or the other key... I don't know and I'm not sure where to look for this kind of information...
- **What was the data in the other token for?** It looked like this:

```
{
  "iss":"https://accounts.google.com",
  "aud":"<redacted>",
  "nbf":<redacted>,
  "iat":<redacted>,
  "exp":<redacted>,
  "jti":"<redacted>"
}
```

- **Why the documentation did not tell me any of these things? Was I supposed to know already? Should I go back to uni?**

Comment: Seems like the documentation may favor Node.js and not include sufficient guidance in other languages.